# How can can i read values from linq query in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, aspnetcoretemplatepack

```
var userData = from x in _context.UserAccount.Where(x => x.UserName == login.UserName)
                                    select new { x.UserFullName, x.Email, x.UserAddress ,x.UserName
                                    ,x.UserPhoto ,x.UserMobileNo,x.UserGender,x.UserQualification,
                                    x.UserDepartment,x.UserDesignation,x.UserPriviledge,x.UserAccountId};

TempData["userData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData);
```

How can I read values from `userData`? and then store in `TempData` to pass on to the next view? Please Help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create `UserViewModel` like below

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserFullName {get; set; }
    public string Email {get; set; }
    public string UserAddress {get; set; }
    // The rest of properties
}
```

Then you can select the result like this

```
var userData = (from x in _context.UserAccount.Where(x => x.UserName == login.UserName)
                    select new UserViewModel 
                    { 
                        UserFullName =  x.UserFullName,
                        Email = x.Email, 
                        UserAddress = x.UserAddress 
                        // The rest of properties 
                    }).ToList();
TempData["userData"] = userData;
```

Finally, in `View` you can get like this

```
@{
  var userData = TempData["userData"] as List<UserViewModel>; // Make sure you've already included _NameSpace_Of_UserViewModel
}
```